# Dual-monitor screen rotation not retained on restart (nvidia-settings)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, nvidia-settings

I have two monitors set up on my desktop PC running Ubuntu 18.04 with an NVIDIA GTX 960 graphics card. I'm running the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

First I open `nvidia-settings` and adjust the monitors so that they are arranged as shown below.

[image]

Then I create a new `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file using the "Save to X Configuration" button. The resulting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is shown below.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 410.79

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL U2414H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-4: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {rotation=left}, DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+840"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After rebooting, the right monitor is no longer rotated, as indicated in the nvidia-settings.

[image]

In case it's important the left monitor is connected via DVI-I (DVI-I-1) and the right monitor is connected via DisplayPort (DP-4).

**What I've tried**

First I checked to see if a `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf` file existed, which I believe would take precedence over `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. The `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf` does not exist.

Next, I tried removing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` completely, then recreating the it file through the nvidia-settings tool. Same behavior as before.

If I remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file then the monitor locations are swapped which indicates that the configuration is being loaded since the behavior is different when the nvidia-settings xorg.conf file is present.

(Nuclear Option) I also tried installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 on an extra internal hard disk. Same behavior as before.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? It's pretty annoying to have to change my monitor rotation every time I start the system.

Comment: I got the same problem on dell laptop :( Have you tried https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305134?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, with your monitors named `DVI-I-1` and `DP-4` a temporary solution would be to set the following command as a startup application:

`xrandr --output DP-4 --rotate right --pos 1920x0 --output DVI-I-1 --pos 0x840`

However i do not find this solution satisfying as this should be handled by Ubuntu and/or Nvidia drivers so that the configuration is instantaneously right at startup rather than waiting for this command to run.

For those who have the same issue, with two monitors having the same resolution `Hres` x `Vres`, the left monitor horizontal and the right vertical:

1. Find your monitor names with:

   `xrandr | grep " connected"`

Now let's assume they are called `Mon1` and `Mon2` (replace with your own names in the subsequent commands).

2. Calculate the vertical position `Vpos` defined as the distance between the top of your horizontal monitor to the top of your vertical monitor. You can see below this is defined this way because the origin is at the top left. If you only know the vertical shift `Vshift` from the bottom, you can easily compute `Vpos` as:

   `Vpos = Vres - Hres - Vshift`

```
       0                        Hres           Hres + Vres
    0                            -------------------
                                 |                 |
                                 |                 |
                                 |                 |
                                 |     Mon2        |
  Vpos    -----------------------|                 |
          |                      |  Vres x Hres    |
          |                      |                 |
          |         Mon1         |                 |
          |                      |                 |
          |     Hres x Vres      |                 |
          |                      |                 |
Vpos+Hres -----------------------|                 |
                     ^           |                 |
             Vshift  |           |                 |
  Vres               v           -------------------
```

3. Create a startup application (search for "startup" in Ubuntu search) with the command below (replace `mon1` and `mon2` with your monitor names, `Hres` with your monitor horizontal resolution, and `Vpos` with the number as you computed from step 2):

   `xrandr --output mon2 --rotate right --pos Hresx0 --output mon1 --pos 0xVpos`

You should be able to easily generalize to monitors with different resolutions or with different alignments.